# Simple SQL to Eloquent Query (Laravel)

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables: users (Users) and groups (Groups).

```
    Users
    -----------------
    id | username | group
     1 | Bob      | 2

    Groups
    -----------------
    id | name
     1 | firstgroup
     2 | secondgroup
```

I would like to display: users.ID, users.username, group.name (1, Bob, secondgroup)
An SQL statement like so would work:

```
SELECT Users.id, Users.username, Groups.name
FROM Users
INNER JOIN 
Groups ON Groups.id = Users.group
```

However, I'm struggling to write this in Eloquent, since there is no "FROM".  At the moment I'm going for something along the lines of the below, using JOINS (http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins)

```
$users = Users::select('id','username', 'Groups.name')->joins('Groups.id', '=', 'id')->get();
```

Now this isn't working - I think the joins has to come before the select but I just can't work it out :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing a few things here...

You're mixing `Eloquent` with the lower-level `DB::table('foo')->select()` syntax. When you want to use Eloquent I suggest you take a look at the [docs about relationships in Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).

You should define your models like so:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Group', 'group');
        // second parameter is necessary because you didnt
        // name the column "group_id" but simply "group"
    }
}

class Group extends Eloquent {
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'group');
    }
}
```

This sets up all the joins you might be needing later. You can then simply use `User::with('group')->all();` and have the query built and run for you.

Comment: Are you sure the group() function is correct? I seem to be getting the data back, but if my user ID is 1, it gives me the data back for the group with the ID of one as well!

Comment: According to your question, user 1 is in group 1.

Comment: Ah no sorry, the user can be in any group (changed the table to reflect what the actual scenario is).  So I'd want to grab all of my users, and then say what group they are in.  Currently, it seems to be matching my user ID, to the group ID, rather than my users 'group' to the group ID.

Comment: in that case you should use `all()` instead of `find(id)`. I've updated my answer. What does the solution currently give you? Always assigned to the group with the same ID as the user?

Comment: You could try removing the custom key `'group'` in the `belongsTo()` declaration, I am not sure if it has to be there.

Comment: http://paste.laravel.com/xPr  Hope that makes more sense... Note I named things plural... which I know shouldn't be done but I didn't realize at the time!

Comment: `$this->hasOne('Groups', 'id');` is wrong. You're always referencing the foreign key, not the local one.

Comment: If I change ('Groups', 'id') to ('Groups', 'group') it says "Unknown column 'groups.group' in 'where clause'" Which is why I was thinking it needed to be the ID, as thats the only thing it can reference! This is confusing me haha.

Comment: I think you should use `belongsTo` instead of `hasOne` to declare an inverse relation. Also, remove the foreign key setting one one of them and setting the other one to 'group'. Apart from that... no idea. Start over ;-)

Comment: Haha man I don't know... $users = Groups::with('users')->get(); works, but the wrong way around (shows the groups with the users in it, rather than the users and their group).

Comment: You shouldn't use `group` as your column name (multiple reasons), rename it to `group_id`. Then setup your eloquent models.

Answer (score 0):

Database: Query Builder(DB) is not a Eloquent(ORM):

Database query builder you have to inform the table names and the fields, like it says on in your related [link](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins) of laravel docs: **"...provides a convenient, fluent interface to creating and running database queries."** like these query below:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
        ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
        ->get();
```

Eloquent is a ORM - Object related Mapping, it means that your class User is related to the table **users** (look at you files Migrations) and this class extends the Model Class, thus you can access the methods like these bellow:

```
class User extends Models
{
    public static function usersWithGroups(){
        return User::select('id', 'name', 'email')->with('groups')->get();
    }
}
```

Observe that method is into the class User, so you can access that in a static way **"User::"**, using Eloquent you'll have many hidden static methods that will improve you time codding, because you are inheriting de Model methods, to more details visit the Eloquent Docs at: [Eloquent Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates)